# Can I repair this motherboard damage?

Tags: surface-mount, repair, electrolytic-capacitor, motherboard

I accidentally knocked a SMD electrolytic capacitor off the motherboard of an ASUS laptop I was stripping down to clean. It looks like the copper pad came off with one of the legs. So My questions are:

1. Am I likely to be able to repair this myself? If so, any brief explanation or links appreciated. Part of my problem is knowing how to ensure any replacement of the copper pad is connected to the circuit.
2. If I cannot repair, what effect is this likely to have? I have not been able to find a circuit diagram but the location is very near to the fan and heatsink and away from most other components. Probably a dumb question but, can I assume it is related to the fan operation? Am I likely to do further damage by attempting to use the laptop without a repair? Will it even work?
3. The final pic below shows another identical capacitor on the board. I have been told it is a tantalum capacitor 15uF 25v however I have not been able to source an exact replacement. Can anyone advise a suitable more readily available alternative.

Many thanks!

[image: Close-up of space where capacitor was]

[image: Location of capacitor]

[image: Bottom view of capacitor]

[image: Side view of capacitor]

[image: Another capacitor - same spec]

Comment: You can try and scrape off the soldermask from the copper that the pad used to connect to and solder something to the cap (copper tape or wire). The capacitor looks like an electrolytic, there are plenty of resources on this and other sites on matching bypass capacitors specs

Comment: @Dennis:  That looks more like a solid aluminum capacitor than a tantalum capacitor.  Regardless, it can be fixed if you are good with a soldering iron.

Comment: Use a sharp exacto knife to scrape the soldermask off that copper that's leftover (the green stuff).   DRAG it, don't cut.  You'll find it kind of crumbles and falls away. Then you'll have a place to solder your new cap to.

Comment: This one is a bit tricky because you have to avoid destroying the vias on the part where the pad pulled off. The other pad is still there but the copper pour will pull a lot of heat from the soldering iron. If the part isn't visibly bashed it can likely be replaced on the board (observe polarity!). You might want to solicit help from a friend with deft soldering iron hands and X-acto knife skills.